# Tensorflow-GPU Error - Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am installing Tensor flow.

I was having trouble installing through Anaconda, so I uninstalled everything including Python, and downloaded Python 3.5 from here:

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-352/

After installing Python 3.5 I installed PyCharm, and set my path variables so that it could find the Python folder.

Then I used command prompt to install tensorflow using:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

Anyway, it installed tensorflow and the other stuff like numpy, protobuf, etc
I set up a project in PyCharm and set the interpreter to the default one located in the Python35 folder.

I opened up the Python console within Pycharm and typed:

```
import tensorflow
```

to get this error:

```
import tensorflow
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Justin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module(mname)
      File "C:\Users\Justin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Justin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
      File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
        module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Justin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
        _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
      File "C:\Users\Justin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
      File "C:\Users\Justin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
        module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Justin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

I hope that is enough detail for someone to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some dependencies. I would recommend to rebuild it from scratch. Use [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) for Windows.

You need to fulfill the requirements for running TF GPU.